# MariaDB automatic back-up mode

Tags: wordpress, mariadb

I like having automatic backups, and I would like one for my MariaDB databases. I want it so in the event the MariaDB gets killed(e.g. OOM Killer during a DoS attack), there's a backup mode that starts running to handle my WordPress install. How can I do this(cronjob, settings, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your wordpress web server and database to handle the maximum amount of connections your the RAM/CPU that your VPS provides. In that case a DoS attack with exhaust connections by not trigger an OOM Killer.

If you want resource scaling look at some of the AWS autoscaling to expand/reduce the hardware resources as utilization occurs.